# Abstraction in Operating Ssytem

Tags: interface, operating-system, abstraction

I am very new to operating systems, that's why this question may be very fundamental.

According to the resources which I have read, all program icons, desktop surface, and other symbols of files and folders are generated by the graphical user interface so that the computer-users can manage some processes easily. This is very senseful.

However, after this definition, I started to face the phrase "abstraction". For example, these resources say that file systems are an abstraction.

Actually, I am a little bit confused with the phrase "abstraction". Besides, I cannot understand the difference between abstraction and graphical user interface. Is there anyone who can explain what the abstraction is in operating systems and the difference between abstraction and GUI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **abstraction** | əbˈstrakʃ(ə)n |
>   noun *[mass noun]*
>
> 1. the quality of dealing with ideas rather than events [..]
> 2. the process of considering something independently of its associations or attributes [..]
> 3. the process of removing something [..]
>
> ORIGIN
>   late Middle English: from Latin ***abstractio(n-)***, from
>   the verb ***abstrahere*** **‘draw away’**.

An *abstraction* in this context is generally anything that simplifies something to a more understandable form. A computer works just with blips of electricity. That is rather difficult to comprehend on a day-to-day basis. Those electric impulses are first abstracted to "ones and zeros" or "bits". Those are further abstracted to form *numbers*. Those numbers are used in specific ways to represent *readable characters*. Bits are also used in certain ways to store data on a spinning disk of metal or in chips, which we generally call a *file system*. That file system is made visible in a hierarchical form using "files" and "directories". That hierarchy is made visible in a GUI using windows and icons. Interacting with those things is abstracted into using a "mouse" to push around those "icons", which in the end translates back down to moving electric impulses around on metal.

All those abstractions allow you to use a computer without having to be aware of the underlying things that are going on to make it happen.